# How to enforce (and automatically refactor if possible) passing string props to React components without brackets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webstorm

I am currently refactoring a React application; one of the tasks in this refactor is removing brackets from string props in components (so `<Component foo={"bar"} />` becomes `<Component foo="bar" />`).

Is there any way to perform this automatically across the whole project using Prettier or ESLint, and enforce it from now on?

Ideally, I would also like WebStorm to recognize if a prop is of `string` type - now, when I write a component IDE automatically opens brackets for all required props and I would need to delete them manually and then write whatever I need to pass.

I tried to find Prettier or ESLint rules enforcing this format, I also looked for WebStorm setting or plugin but found none.

Comment: [react/jsx-curly-brace-presence](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-curly-brace-presence.md) sounds like what you want

Comment: to get WebStorm auto-add quotes instead of brackets, try setting **Add for JSX attributes:** to **Quotes** in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other** to have quotes added always, or to **Based on type** to have either braces or quotes auto-completed depending on props type

Comment: @lena this works. Thank you!